# Unique constraints with null values as valid row

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Hi I am inserting a bunch of data in a batch process.

The final output should be a table like this. Observe that here `Name, Address_id` pair are UNIQUE. `Address_id` can be NULL but only once for the given pair `Name, Address_id`

```
Name    address_id
———      —————
“Richard”   1
“Richard”   2
“Richard”   NULL
“Richard    3
“James”     1
“James”     2
“James”     NULL
“James”     3
```

However I can not guarantee the uniqueness of the pair when `address_id` is NULL. Another Pair `(“Richard”, NULL)` would be consider valid if I add an `INDEX UNIQUE (name, address_id)`

Then, if I add the following indexes (found it googling)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_employers_on_name_and_address_id 
    ON employers(name, address_id) 
    WHERE address_id IS NOT NULL


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_employers_on_name 
    ON employers(name) 
    WHERE address_id IS NULL
```

All `(<NAME>, NULL)` pairs are not allowed because already exists a NAME unique

Some ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Do the last two indexes do what you want?  They seem to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_employers_on_name 
    ON employers(name) 
    WHERE address_id IS NULL ;
```

is a *partial index* that only applies when `address_id is null`.  It will allow only one `NULL` value per `name`.  Non-`NULL` values for `address_id` have no affect on the uniqueness.

This appears to do what you want.